# Problem on hosting webpage on localhost using nodejs

Tags: node.js, localhost

I have made a node program which hosts html files along with other types of files(if there are any) on localhost:3000. everything's working fine but for some reason, 404.html doesn't pop up when I am entering a wrong path name.
Here is the node program given below:

https://pastebin.com/4vtSQsva

I have a folder called `public` in the root directory of the project and that's where all the html css js and other files which are hosted are there.
pls help me out.

Comment: the simpler the code the better. Try out using switch statement instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch it will help you to troubleshoot

Comment: thanks for that but it didn't seem to help me. Also I would like to stay in the current form of the code due to some other reasons(please don't take that personally). It would be nice if you kindly state why is the 404 not loading, Fyi i tried giving a console.log there and i found that the log didn't pop in the terminal and the page kept on loading

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this:

```
if (!exists) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    filePath = path.resolve('./404.html');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
    return;
}
```

With this:

```
if (!exists) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    filePath = path.resolve('./404.html');
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, contents) {                        
        if (!err) {                            
             res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
             res.end(contents);
        } else {                            
             console.log(err);
        };
    });
 }
```

Did your **404.html** file placed in */public* folder?

If so it should be `filePath = path.resolve('./public/404.html');`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that didnt seem to solve my problem. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1S7u8YFv7zBKv2gjK1TfBJ-fI_-4uCe/view?usp=sharing) you can find the screen recording of the error

Comment: @AarushPaul Can re-create your code in code sandbox. I do not know your file structure so may be the issues caused by it.